# Google Script : Create a range of values from loop "for" indice

Tags: google-sheets, scripting

I'm trying to make my hand on Google Script and I hit a dumb problem.
I try to make a set of values in a row of a spreadsheet (10th row), using the loop indice "i", but I only get a set of 10 columns with the value 10 in each cell, and not "**1,2,3 ...**" . The value doesn't incriment from one cell to another, just stay at the top.
Is it a problem with the loop usage or the "**getRange**" ?

```
function onOpen() {

 var document = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = document.getSheets()[0];

 for (var i=0; i < 10;i++);
 {    
  sheet.getRange(10,1,1,i).setValue(i);
 }

}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

God d***,

I found.

After checking even this website, with exactly what I needed [BAZROBERT : APPS SCRIPT BASICS (4) – LOOPS](https://www.bazroberts.com/2017/04/13/apps-script-basics-loops/), it didn't work.
It's the "**;**" after "**for (var i=0; i < 10;i++)**", that bothered.